# Is there a pattern for including Release Pipelines in Azure Dev Ops via Source Control and Automation?

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, azure-automation

Our team uses Azure Dev Ops for our source control and release pipelines. The release pipelines are not included in our source control and are created through ADO UI. These can be very complex; I exported one release and it was 7500 lines of json. I would like these pipeline definitions to be in the same source control as our source code for easy maintenance and review.

I see that there are tools for exporting the pipeline definition to json and an option in the UI to create a pipeline by importing json. Is there a pattern to use automation to leverage these import/export functions and have a pipeline that is updated based on the definition in my repo?

We are currently just using the UI to update the pipelines without any additional version control or review controls. I'm expecting some functionality like GitHub Actions where the pipeline definition is contained within the repo and automation picks up the files.

Comment: I've found this https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/11272. Is this completed or still on the roadmap? I see an answer to export the template and use the create API - is that a recommended pattern?

Comment: Use YAML pipelines. If you're using TFS/Azure DevOps Server and don't have a version that supports YAML pipelines, that's a great reason to upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to version control your pipelines, I suggest that you start using the yaml pipelines that exist in Azure Devops.

These can handle both build and release pipelines. The "Releases" tab in the GUI becomes obsolete, as all pipelines (both build and release) instead show up in the "Pipelines" tab. For release pipelines, use the `deployment` job type, which gives you access to automatic artifact handling and environment management.

Edit: So to answer the actual question, I do not know any way to version control the GUI (classic) pipelines. My strong recommendation is to migrate to yaml pipelines.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to version control your pipelines you can make use of YAML Pipelines instead of directly using Release pipeline. You can also use the same YAML pipeline for the Release deployment.

To create a simple YAML pipeline > From your Repository:-

[image]

[image]

Sample YAML script:-

```yaml
# Starter pipeline

# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.

# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:

# https://aka.ms/yaml

  

trigger:

- keyvaultsecrets

  

pool:

vmImage: ubuntu-latest

  

steps:

- script: echo Hello, world!

displayName: 'Run a one-line script'

  

- script: |

echo Add other tasks to build, test, and deploy your project.

echo See https://aka.ms/yaml

displayName: 'Run a multi-line script'
```

[image]

Output of YAML pipeline:-

[image]

***Use the Deployment Job type for release pipelines to automatically manage the environment and handle artifacts, refer below:-***

[image]

**YAML script with version control of deployment job:-**

```yaml
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
  imageName: mydockerimage
  registryName: myregistry
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build job
    steps:
    - script: |
        docker build -t $(registryName)/$(imageName):$(tag) .
        docker push $(registryName)/$(imageName):$(tag)
      displayName: 'Build and push Docker image'

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy job
    environment: 'production'
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: KubernetesManifest@0
            inputs:
              action: 'deploy'
              kubernetesServiceEndpoint: 'myKubernetesServiceConnection'
              namespace: 'default'
              manifests: |
                $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/kubernetes/deployment.yaml
            displayName: 'Deploy to Kubernetes'
```

Because the above pipeline is version controlled using YAML files, collaboration and change tracking are made simpler. Using version control technologies like Git, any updates made to the pipeline can be recorded and examined, including changes to the deployment job or its tasks.

Now, You can version control every **yaml** pipeline with its build number that is available at the URL of your pipeline, Refer below:-

[image]

***Due to the availability of all pipeline runs under the Pipelines tab, the release pipeline is also rendered obsolete. Refer below:-***

[image]